# Traversing through a map with nested lists as values

Tags: java

Here is a `Map`, with a `String` key (textfile) and value (`List` of integers):

```
aaa.txt : {(The=[11], put=[8], I'm=[1], by=[5], you,=[3, 7], the=[4, 10], key=[6, 9]}
bbb.txt : {do.=[12], to=[6], I'm=[1], what=[9], you=[4, 10], want=[11], sure=[2]}
ccc.txt : {just=[10], need=[7], you,=[6], it=[5], than=[3], It's=[1], the=[11]}
```

I want to print it out in this format:

```
you, 3:7, , 6
```

As you can see, I want to print the above format "you," located in `aaa.txt` and `ccc.txt` but not `bbb.txt` so it should be that printed out for the word `you, 3:7, ,6`.

If `you` is not found in bbb.txt, which is isn't, we should have `you, 3:7, "space", 6`. So space is to show that word is not present in the second text file.

Just like that I want to print every word in the MAP's Value and keep. Here is the Map structure of what's above

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<Integer>>> COOLMAP = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String, List<Integer>>>();



EXPECTED/WANTED OUTPUT

a  20, 4:20 ,15
as   ,  , 16:17
by   , 16 ,
```

Comment: In the first line, should there be a `,` after `you`?  `you,=[3, 7]`

Comment: you is also in bbb.txt shouldn't it print 3:7, 4:10, 6 ?

Comment: @anaxin yes in that case it should but, look carefully you and you, are differnt... there is a comma

Comment: @EvanKnowles If there is comma or apostrphe just ignore it

Comment: Please show your attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try iterating through each Map to get all keys. Using a HashSet eliminates duplicates.

```
HashSet<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
        for (Entry<String, HashMap<String, List<Integer>>> entry : COOLMAP.entrySet()) {
            for (Entry<String, List<Integer>> innerEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
                String innerKey = innerEntry.getKey();
                keys.add(innerKey);
            }
```

Then use the keys to search the maps for values.

```
String temp;
        Iterator it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            temp = (String) it.next();
            System.out.print(temp + ", ");
            for (Entry<String, HashMap<String, List<Integer>>> entry : COOLMAP.entrySet()) {
                boolean hasValue = false;
                for (Entry<String, List<Integer>> innerEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
                    String innerKey = innerEntry.getKey();
                    if (innerKey.equals(temp)) {
                        System.out.print(innerEntry.getValue() + ", ");
                        hasValue = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!hasValue) {
                    System.out.print(", ,");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: But this implementation only works for 3 files, i want it work for n files

Comment: Does that work for you now ? I didn't test much let me know if it is ok

Comment: it's not printing the words in order  for example `a  20, 4:20 ,15`
"a" is word FOR That word , `20` is from the value where key is`a.txt` and `4:20` is from `b.txt` and `15` is from `c.txt`